# C++ ostream_iterator creation throws exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Okay, I have the following vector:

```
std::vector< std::pair<std::shared_ptr<std::fstream>, uint32_t> > writer = {
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file1.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c1 },
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file2.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c1 },
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file3.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c2 },
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file4.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c2 },
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file5.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c3 },
    { std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file6.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c3 }
};
```

and then I have the following code:

```
for_each_idx(this->data.begin(), this->data.end(), 0, [&writer](unsigned index, std::vector<float> value) {
     auto it_start  = value.begin();
     auto it_end    = value.begin() + std::min(value.size(), writer.at(index).second);
     auto it_stream = std::ostream_iterator<float>(*writer.at(index).first << std::fixed, ",");

     std::transform(it_start, it_end, it_stream, [](float num){ /* Do stuff */ });
});
```

The problem is at this line:

```
auto it_stream = std::ostream_iterator<float>(*writer.at(index).first << std::fixed, ",");
```

which gives me an `access violation` error. At first I thought it was the `.at(index)` but `index`'s value is correct and yes `writer` and `this->data` vectors have the same size. So, what am I missing?

***EDIT:*** Okay I found a way to make it work. I changed the writer creation:

```
std::vector< std::pair<std::shared_ptr<std::fstream>, uint32_t> > writer;

writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file1.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c1 });
writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file2.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c1 });
writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file3.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c2 });
writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file4.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c2 });
writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file5.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c3 });
writer.push_back({ std::make_shared<std::fstream>("file6.csv", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc), bin_c3 });
```

Still, can someone explain why this works and when I create the `writer` using the initializer list it actually treats every `shared_ptr` as uninitialized pointer?

***EDIT:*** Installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 solved the problem.

Comment: What happens if you use `*(writer.at(index).first)`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. Same result

Comment: if you found a solution you may post it as an answer, but please dont post it in the question

Comment: Well, yes I found a solution, but it still doesn't explain why this didn't work in the first place. So, this solution doesn't actually answer my question.